# Explain plan shows column name in name section?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-execution-plan, explain

I am running a query on production environment.
But, when I lookup the explain plan it show me the column name of table in name column of explain plan.

```
| Id  | Operation                                     | Name                       |

|*  8 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID 

     |
```

`TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID` is a column name.

Comment: check with `select * from all_tables where table_name = 'TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID'` if it shows some rows it **is a table** as well...

Comment: show the whole query and the complete explain plan

Comment: it is quite improbable, for not saying impossible, that the name shows is anything but the element accessed ( table or index ) . In this case, `TRANSACTION_TYPE_IDE` must be a table

Comment: i checked twice, its not a table .